# R - Replace NA with NULL for input into PostgreSQL

Tags: r, postgresql

I am trying to replace `NA` values with `NULL`. The reason being, that I need to input `numeric` values into a PostgreSQL database and keep getting the error: `ERROR: Invalid input syntax for type numeric ""`.

I have tries setting the values to `NA`, an empty string `''`, and `"NULL"` (as a string). None of these have worked.

```
df = data.frame(x=c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'), y=c(1, 2, 3, NA, 5))
df[is.na(df)] = "NULL"
df[is.na(df)] = ""
```

Comment: You cannot have `NULL` as an element in an atomic vector where there are other non-null elements.  `NULL` has zero length and is thereby either removed from the vector or an error is triggered with assignment.  Why won't NA work?  That column class is still numeric

Comment: How are you importing dataframe into database? Using  RODBC? If so, [sqlSave()](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/RODBC/docs/sqlUpdate) which creates tables from data frames does handle NA as NULLs.

Comment: I was just importing manually after exporting as a `csv`. I'll try the `sqlSave()` method though.

Answer (score 3):

If your table is using `numeric`, then converting `NA` to `NaN` should work. `numeric`, as well as `decimal` and `float` support `NaN` (see [Postgres Documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-numeric.html)).

Should your data type be something different, like `integer`, you can coerce `NaN` to `NULL` with `nullif`:

```
nullif(y, 'NaN')
```

Comment: Also works for boolean/logical by converting logical to character first, `y = as.character(mybool)`, then in SQL: `nullif(y, 'NA')::boolean` for NA or `nullify(y, '')::boolean` for blank/empty (e.g, an unset shiny input).